# LL(1) Grammar and parsing

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I'd like some help on how to transform a grammar to LL(1) using factoring. Possibly other techniques but I have already used left recursion
For example I have the question

```
S--> 1X1F|2X2F|1X
X--> 1X|0
F--> 0F|ε
```

ε denotes a termination without another letter.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, this is already LL(1) as we can decide on which rule to use by seeing just 2 symbols down. What I was confused on was the rest  of the symbols. But from the research I have done, I would say this is LL(1)